# SONAR Code coverage not getting reflected

Tags: sonarqube

Issue :
SONAR Code coverage is not getting reflected on Azure DevOps.

We are developing application in C# .NET , the test methods are running successfully however when we push the build in pipeline of Azure DevOps, the code coverage percentage still remains 0%.We tried checking all the possible settings but aren't able to reach on any solution yet. Can anyone let me know which all areas we should be checking to resolve this issue?
Let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: Please show how you run the tests and how the sonar scanner is run.

Comment: We run the test in Visual Studio Test Projects wherein we come to know if the test method is running/failing. Post successful execution of test method and doing check in of the file we run a pipeline on Azure DevOps wherein all the SONAR alarms are listed. This is the process we follow.. and I am not aware about how the SONAR scanner is run..

Comment: Are you able to share your pipeline then? At least the steps that are related to SonarQube, most probably prepare and end.